# Transitioning svg text opacity

Tags: svg, d3.js

Has anybody ever had any issues with transitioning the opacity of an SVG text element?  I'm using both the fill-opacity style and the stroke-opacity style to fade the text elements into and out of existence.  It works fine on most browsers, but doesn't transition at all in Chrome on Mac -- the text just pops in and out all at once.

I tried setting the "opacity" attribute in addition to fill-opacity and stroke-opacity and that does seem to make it work, although now I see a weird flicker effect just before and after the transition runs.  It's like it's setting it to opacity=1 for a split second before it sets it to 0 and then transitions to 1.

Another interesting thing is that other shapes (circle, rect) fade in and out just fine with nearly identical code to what I'm using with text.

This does seem to be weirdness with a specific browser, but I'm wondering about other people's experiences with opacity on text elements.  Are there tricks to get it to behave consistently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What version of Chrome are you using? I noticed a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45747) in Chrome dev some time ago when working on the [word cloud](http://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/) but it appears to have been fixed as of 19.0.1077.3 dev.  Perhaps the fix hasn't made it into your particular version yet?

In my case, using `opacity` fixed the problem temporarily. The flicker effect could be due to exponent notation not being parsed for very small numbers; you can try using `1e-6` instead of `0` to get around this.

Comment: I'm still on Chrome v18 so I'll check back once v19 comes out.  For no, opacity does the trick and your tip about using 1e-6 instead of 0 got rid of the flicker.  Awesome!  Probably pushing my luck here, but any thoughts on this similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/10144934/1040479

Answer (score 0):

For an animation I made some months ago I toggled the style and used `webkit-transition`, in combination with `visibility: hidden`. This seems to work well. If that doesn't work, you could try transitioning to an opacity near zero.