# D3 font-size transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

Why do I get a "fly-in" effect when I try to transition font size in D3? See my minimal example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Test text transtion</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js">
</script>

<body>
  <button>Toggle</button>
  <script>
    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    var myLabel = svg.append('text')
      .attr('y', 100)
      .text('Watch me.');
    var toggle = false;
    d3.selectAll('button').on('click', function() {
      toggle = !toggle;
      myLabel.transition()
        .style('font-size', toggle ? '2em' : '1em');
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

That is obviously not the desired effect. I just want the text to grow or shrink in place without much fanfare.  In [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144934/transition-font-size-on-chrome-after-zoom-in), someone else defines a custom tween. Does that mean there's no easier way? I'd be very surprised because this is a commonplace effect, and the built-in interpolator handles opacity and font-weight just fine.

Also if I define a custom tween, does it mean that the other built-in transitions I current have (opacity etc.)  will need to be queued since only one transition can be active on a element at a given time?

Comment: @RobertLongson Okay, I edited the question in response to your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

text-align="middle" will put the text anchor point in the bottom middle which would seem to be what you want here. If you chain transitions they will operate sequentially.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Test text transtion</title>

<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js">
</script>
<body>
<button>Toggle</button>
<script>
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
var myLabel = svg.append('text')
    .attr('x', 80)
    .attr('y', 100)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('font-size', '1em')
    .text('Watch me.');
var toggle = false;
d3.selectAll('button').on('click', function() {
    toggle = !toggle;
    myLabel.transition()
        .attr('font-size', '2em')
        .duration(500)
        .transition()
        .attr('font-size', '1em')
        .duration(500);
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking why the transition start with such a big font

Comment: But it's still flying in! By that I mean text starts out as big as the svg frame and then reduces to the specified size. I want the `1em` grow to `2em` as though you're inflating a balloon, and then back as though you're letting the air out.

Comment: You mean like this?

Comment: I mean rather like [this](https://jsbin.com/dowaqi/2/edit?html,output), but you've shown me that using `.attr` instead of `.style` for `font-size` is the way to go. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The fly-in effect happens because you need to specify a font-size first.  I ran into that recently.
Try adding this before the transition:

```
.style('font-size', 'Nem')
```

N = your starting font size.  And stick with either style() or attr() for your font options, as mixing the 2 can also cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use linear easing for a smooth transition.

```
d3.selectAll('button').on('click', function() {
    toggle = !toggle;
    myLabel.transition()
        .attr('font-size', toggle ? '2em' : '1em')
        .ease('linear')
```

Answer (score 0):

D3 doesn't support CSS transition.

Instead you should use:

```
.attr('font-size', FONT_SIZE);
```

Comment: [Please format your text properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)